# Why am I getting a Pylance error "Object of type 'A*' is not callable" in VSCode when using generics?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, generics, typing, pylance

I'm attempting to write a generic class in Python 3.11 that should be able to process a list of elements using different processing classes (`A` or `B` in this example). My goal is to use the type variable `T` to specify the processing class that should be used.

**Clarification**: Each element `x` within the list `X`requires an individual initialization of the subclass `A` or `B`, so initializing is only possible withing the `process()` method.

Here's my code:

```py
from typing import List, Self, TypeVar, Generic

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, x):
        return x + 1

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, x):
        return x + 2

T = TypeVar("T", A, B)

class ListProcessor(Generic[T]):
    """Apply a Transformer to the individual list elements."""

    def __init__(self, processor: T):
        self.processor_class = processor
        self.processors: List[T] = []  # <- Pylance complains! see error message (1)

    def process(self, X) -> List:
        x_processed = []
        for x in X:
            proc: T = self.processor_class()  # <- Pylance complains! see error message (2)
            result = proc.process(x)
            x_processed.append(result)
            self.processors.append(proc)
        return x_processed

lp = ListProcessor(B)
lp.process([1, 2, 3])
```

The output of the above is:

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

which is what I expect. But while the code runs, Pylance type checker complains in VSCode.

1. For the line `self.processors: List[T] = []`, I get:

   > Variable not allowed in type expression PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
   > T: ~T
   > (constant) T: Unknown
2. For the line `proc: T = self.processor_class()`, I get:

   > Object of type "A*" is not callablePylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
   > Object of type "B*" is not callablePylancereportGeneralTypeIssues

I'm struggling to understand these error messages. Could someone help clarify why these errors occur and how I can fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inded I totaly miss read `self.processors: List[T] = []`, sorry :')
Though it seems like vscode is not complaining about anything here, I think changing the `processor: T` by `processor: Type[T]` and the process function to `proc: T = self.processor_class()` to `proc = self.processor_type()` should do the job.

Comment: Super thank you @Atako! Just for clarification, I had to change the argument in `__init__` from `processor: T` to `processor: Type[T]` :) I had to read your answer a few times to see what you mean ^^ Also, the reference to `self.processor_type()` is not clear to me, this class method doesnt exit!? Anyways, I could resolve it thanks to your answer! :)

Comment: Yes my bad, will playing around with you're code I renamed things and I renamed `processor` to `processor_type` xD

Answer (score 0):

The line `self.processors: List[T] = []` should be `self.processors: List[T] = []` because `self.processors` is a `list` that will contain instances of type `T`.

The line `proc: T = self.processor_class()` should be `proc: T = self.processor_class` because we are assigning the class itself, not an instance of the class.

Finnaly, in the line, `lp = ListProcessor(B)`, you need to instantiate the `B` class by using `B()` because you want to pass an instance of class `B` to the `ListProcessor` constructor.

Comment: thank you for four help! that doesn't sound right though, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding your answer? 
1) I cannot see the difference between the two: " `self.processors: List[T] = []` should be `self.processors: List[T] = []` " 2) `proc: T = self.processor_class()` doesn't work here because I need an individual class initialization per list element `x`, so I have to initialize 3) doesnt work either because of 2)